# How to handle questions that result in bad practice

Tags: discussion, questions

I'll start with a recent **example** to illustrate what I mean: [php: skip '$this' in object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304666/php-skip-this-in-object-class)

The question in this example basically asks if there is a way to use object-oriented syntax in `PHP` the same way it appears in some other languages. In `PHP`, you always have to reference the object, commonly resulting in a bunch of `$this->` in your object methods, while other languages often extend the scope of object attributes to the local scope of the object's methods. In other words, you can just use variables declared in the class locally within the functions, no need to reference `this` object.

Since it's not natively possible in `PHP`, all workaround methods involve some trickiness (the asker was apparently aware of that since he asked for a "magic method"). But in the end, it's **considered bad practice** to avoid this specific syntax because it supposedly lowers readability.

My actual question or rather discussion topic here is: **How should we handle questions like this** that basically come down to asking for something that's considered bad practice in its respective context, but not necessarily in another context?

**To clarify**, I'm not talking about question like *"How to take user input and evaluate it as code?"* which can only lead to problems and bad practice, but rather questions like *"Is there a way to implement [feature in some language] in [some other language]?"*, which might well result in bad practice because the feature possibly doesn't exist in the other language for a good reason.

Answer (score 6):

The asker might come from a different language or background and be **used to** what he's trying to achieve in the new language. Even if it's considered bad practice in that language, it's supported in another one, so his question is **totally legitimate**. That being said, bad practice is called that way for a reason, so it should not be encouraged.

My suggestions to handle this kind of question correctly are:

- **Comment on the question** pointing out that its goal is considered bad practice in the specific language or context. Maybe add links that explain this in more detail.
- **Post an answer** only if it still contains a way to achieve the question's goal as much as possible. This might be a workaround, some magic method or some tricky out-of-the box way to (ab)use existing methods. Ways to achieve something similar with some limitations are also fine. But also **include a warning** in the answer, explaining that and why it's a bad idea to do whatever is trying to be done.
- **Comment on answers** that don't include such a warning or don't point out the limitations of the suggested solution to make sure it's there, possibly ending up in the author editing his answer to include such warnings.

What I think **should not be done** is:

- Close or even delete the question for reasons such as "Off-topic"
- Post an answer stating it's not possible and justify it by referring to how it's bad practice (this only applies if it actually is possible, of course saying it's not when it simply isn't possible is totally fine)
- Discourage others from posting answers containing suggestions of workarounds or tricks (but see the third bullet point above)
- Downvote answers for the only reason that they contain suggestions that should not be implemented (instead see the third bullet point above)
- Downvote the question for the only reason that it asks for something which is bad practice
- Point the asker to a tutorial or manual, implying he doesn't understand the canonical way to do it (especially if said way is pointed out in the question and the question asks for an alternative way)

Of course, I have good reasons to believe this is the correct way, which I'll point out now:

1. **The question is legitimate.** If the feature exists somewhere, it might very well exist in the context of the question (or rather of the tags). The asker probably doesn't know why the feature doesn't exist natively in this language. He might be new to the language and confused by the differences to languages he is used to. He might want to write his code similar to his code in other languages to ease cross-references and understandability for others knowing only those other languages. There could be a reason several languages have to be used in the same project and shall be written as similarly as possible.
2. **We are a Q&A site**. Not a *Q&only-get-an-A-if-we-think-you-should-do-what-you-ask*. Our role is to provide answers to questions, not to judge questions and provide advice based on our judgment. It is important to **educate people about good practice** and reasons some things should not be done. In fact, so important it should be pointed out in the comments to the question as well as in each answer. But it's not more important than providing **good, accurate and true answers**. Pointing it out should not be at the expense of a good or correct answer. Intentionally giving a wrong answer or lying to someone to prevent him making something stupid is not what we should do.
3. **He's going to find out** some way. Maybe on another Q&A site, maybe on some blog, maybe just randomly stumbling over it himself. If there is a way, he will probably find it. The problem is, when he does, there is a serious chance that he **will not simultaneously be warned** about the dangers and the reasons his attempt is a bad idea. He will have to find out the hard way someday when it matters. If we instead **provide guidance** by telling him how it can be done, but at the same time explaining why it's dangerous and not advisable, he will have learned a lot and have a positive experience with us. And he will understand the problem and be able to transfer it to similar situations, avoiding the same mistake in a slightly different context.
4. **We care for quality** in both questions and answers. *Timeless quality*. If a question or an answer is well written, understandable and comprehensible, then it's probably worthy of upvoting. Even if the content is questionable from a "good practice" point of view. The content's viability or even correctness may change in the future when things about the language change. The visual and semantic quality won't. Especially if it makes clear where the dangers and limitations are, it's helpful and valuable.
5. **We seek completeness.** Ideally, when someone types a question into a search engine, he will find at least one result on here. And questions about features existing in different languages are common. If, then, he not only finds an answer to his question, but also related content and warnings about things to be wary about, he will have learned more than intended by his initial question and leave with a good impression of this site. Or register and stay. It's all about reputation.